# BigQuery query extremely slow when adding JOIN

Tags: sql, performance, join, google-bigquery

This is my first post in here, so please let me know if I've done anything wrong when posting my question.

I started learning SQL from scratch about three weeks ago, and so I'm fairly new to the whole concept and community and therefore I've probably made a lot of mistakes in my code, but here goes.

I'm struggling with a query, that I'm writing in BigQuery. BigQuery's "validator" has validated the code, so on 'paper' it's seems good, but it takes forever to run. It runs to a point where I stop it, because it has passed an hour. I've been looking in to streamlining my sql-coding so that the proces could run smoother and therefore run faster, but I've hit a wall, where I think I'm out of questions, that could provide me with a useful answer.

(Edit)
What I wan't from this query is a dataset that can help me make a visualisation that creates a timeline based on the dates/timestamps that read_started_at provides.
On this timeline I want a distinct count of reader_id's on the given day/DATE_TRUNC(timestamp). Google Data Studio can make a distinct count of the reader_id's, so I'm in doubt, whether making the distinct count in my query, will slow down or speed up the process in the long run?
Lastly I wanna divide the reader_id's into two groups(dimensions) based on whether they are on a monthly- or yearly-based subscription to see, if one group is more represented at the given read_started_at's, and therefore more active on the website, than the other. This division is supposed to be provided by the chargebee_plan_id where multiple subscriptions are available therefore there's the condition 'yearly' or 'monthly'. The reader_id and membership_id contains the same data and are therefore JOINED upon.
(Edit end)

I really hope that somebody here can help me out. Any advice is appreciated.

My query is the following:

```
WITH memberships AS (
        SELECT im.chargebee_plan_id, im.membership_id
        FROM postgres.internal_reporting_memberships AS im 
        WHERE (im.chargebee_plan_id LIKE 'yearly' OR im.chargebee_plan_id LIKE 'monthly') 
          AND  im.started_at >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 365 day)
                    ),

     readers AS     (       
        SELECT  ip.reader_id, DATE_TRUNC(CAST(ip.read_started_at AS DATE), DAY) read_start
        FROM postgres.internal_reporting_read_progresses AS ip 
        WHERE ip.reader_id LIKE '%|%' AND ip.read_started_at >= (TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 365 day)
                    ))

SELECT  reader_id, read_start, m.chargebee_plan_id
FROM    readers AS r
  JOIN memberships AS m
  ON r.reader_id LIKE m.membership_id
```

Cheers

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Change your join to use `=` instead of `LIKE` if possible.  This might mean casting in your `_id` columns inside of the CTEs if they are of different datatypes.

Comment: The question has now been edited. Thank you for the help @GordonLinoff

Comment: And THANK YOU @rtenha ! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Reposting my comment as an answer as it solved the problem.

Use an `=` instead of a `LIKE` for the join condition.